# Unity Call a class function from other script

Tags: c#, function, class, unity-game-engine

I have 2 scripts: Console and Test. I want to call "appendLogLine" function from Test script but cannot get it working.

Console.cs:

```
public class ConsoleController
{

    public void appendLogLine(string line)
    {
        if (line == "Unable to process command ''")
            return;

        Debug.Log(line);

        if (scrollback.Count >= ConsoleController.scrollbackSize)
        {
            scrollback.Dequeue();
        }
        scrollback.Enqueue(line);

        log = scrollback.ToArray();
        if (logChanged != null)
        {
            logChanged(log);
        }
    }
}
```

Test.cs:

```
public GameObject ConsoleObject;

public void CallLog()
{

    ConsoleObject.GetComponent<ConsoleController>.appendLogLine ("Test123");
}
```

I get error with that: "error CS0119: Expression denotes a `method group', where a`variable', `value' or`type' was expected"

Comment: `ConsoleObject.GetComponent<ConsoleController>().appendLogLine ("Test123");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use `GetComponent`, the script you are performing `GetComponent` on must inherit from `MonoBehaviour`. This is not the case here.

`public class ConsoleController {}` should be `public class ConsoleController : MonoBehaviour {}`

Now, you use `GetComponent` on the `ConsoleController` script. Note that you forgot "()" too. You must include that since `GetComponent` is a function.

It should be this:

```
ConsoleObject.GetComponent<ConsoleController>().appendLogLine("Test123");
```